# ModelBinder in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, modelbinders

I use ASP.NET Core 5, I want to create a custom model binder for every property that ends with `ParenteseIcon` and when I got the data in the server property will be like this (Client user => Value and server value => (Value))

How can I create model binder to solve my issue?

```
Client value => text
In the server => value convert to (text)
```

Comment: I might be refering to what "AutoMapper" is doing, else I'm not clear about the question

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to solve here? It's unclear to me why you are even looking at custom model binding

Comment: I want to user client write text in the input and in the server and my view model I got (text) by default, I knew that this happened by model binder

Comment: > `I want to user client write text in the input and in the server and my view model I got (text) by default, I knew that this happened by model binder`

Yes, you are right, this is the model binder's job. But it's unclear to know how to bind the view model based on the user entered value, you can create an example to explain more detail about the entered value and view model, for example, user entered value `1001|Tom`, in the model binder, we will bind the value to view model (student: Id and Name property.)